# Is a high open circuit voltage still beneficial when you have a high voltage/frequency pulse arc starter?

Tags: voltage, transformer, pulse, arc

In welding, I know a high open circuit voltage is a major factor in the strength/quality of your arc when you scratch start, but how much of a factor is it when you have a pulse starting mechanism? Is it still necessary to have a high OCV to maintain a strong arc or is does the starter reduce its importance? If I have two identical welders that put out 200 amps at 50 OCV DC and I connect their secondaries in series, does that give me a 200 amp 100 OCV welder? Is that the only way to increase OCV, by increasing the total power? By extension, how is the OCV related to the voltage during welding? Is it a linear correlation?

Comment: what do you mean by "pulse starting mechanism"? Is is a new way to weld or a machine you scraped off from somewhere?

Comment: the old transformer arc welders varied the current by adjusting the coupling between the windings. As soon as you struck the arc, the voltage would drop. How much it would drop would depend on the coupling - more coupling more Amps. From recollection, the arc voltage is only a couple of volts - depends on the arc length and Amps. The inverter welders have a separate circuit that imposes a high voltage on top of the low voltage dc supply to ionise the air and promote an arc. One reason why they strike easier.